# I have errors while installing phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I've been trying for several days now but I couldn't still install phonegap on My system,  I try to install it from the node command prompt 
but it gives me this errors :

> network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND  network you are behind a proxy or you
>   have a bad network  system windows_NT 6.2.9200 command c:\ \program
>   files \ \nodejs \ \ \ \node. exe  error EPERM, open C: \npm-debug.log

Comment: http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Comment: it didn't work, I tried it,  do I have to be online before I can install phonegap?

Comment: of course you need to... npm DOWNLOADS all needed dependencies before you can do anything with phonegap..